# Running time of binary search with comparison

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have this code:

```
public static int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    int n = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
        char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
        int diff = c1 - c2;
        if (diff != 0) {
            return diff; 
        }
    }
    return s1.length() - s2.length();
}

public static boolean exists(String word, String[] dict) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = dict.length-1;
    while (left <= right) {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        int comparison = compare(dict[middle], word); 
        if (comparison < 0) {
            left = middle+1;
        } 
        else if (comparison > 0) {
            right = middle-1;
        } else {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

I have to calculate the complexity of the exists function.
I said It's O(K*logN), while the N is the number of elements in the array, and K is the number of letters in word.
The answer is O(logN), does it mean I wasn't supposed to include `compare` function complexity in my calculation?

Comment: I think the answer only considers what happens when you vary the length of the array, keeping the word lengths constant. Similarly, if I only vary the word lengths, while keeping the length of array constant, it would be O(K). I would say these are both valid interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm will run `O(logn)` times where `n = dict.length` and for every iteration it requires `O(K)` where `K` is the **maximum (*)** length of the words.
Thus using multiplicative principle (or [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), your algorithm requires `O(K*logn)` time complexity.

(*) Above I stated maximum length even though inside your function you use math.min, but consider the case where you compare largest word with second largest and both are `O(K)` of length, so in worst case scenario it's `O(maximum length)`.